# Prevent multiple MvxImageViews from downloading image in ListView

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am building an app which uses an MvxListView that is binded to a list of elements. in the template there is an MvxImageView which is binded to an imageURL. The problem I am experiencing is that once I flick on the list and scroll many items down it takes a long time for the images to load. I can see that there are many downloading threads in the android log and thats why it takes a long time for the images to load. Is there a way to stop the imageview from downloading the images untill scrolling stops? I have been trying to work out solutions but I can manage to make it work.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: You could play with limiting the amount of concurrent downloads in the DownloadCache plugin?

Comment: @Cheesebaron will that solve the issue? if I scroll wont the images pile up in a queue? or will the request be discarded?

Comment: It will queue them up.

Comment: @Cheesebaron so its not good. because if you scrolled 20 itmes it will downlaod them one by one and you will wait... I have actually came up with a solution where each listviewitem has a timer and once it elapses it downloads the image, the timer is reseted every time the view gets recycled.